# Problem compiling Junit classes

Tags: java, junit

I have my java project compiled and working fine but now I want to compile the JUnit tests and I'm having some trouble doing it.
I have all the tests.java in `/test/model`, so I tried doing this:

```
javac -cp org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ./test/model/Mytestclass.java
```

But it doesn't detect the classes of my project so it fails.

I also tried with this `classpath`:

```
CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/junit4.jar:/build/model:/src/model
```

In `/build/model`, there are the .class files and, in `/src/model` there are the main Java files of my project.

How can I compile this?

Comment: What is the package name you are using for your junit test classes?

Comment: The compiling error is: cannot find symbol. For example, if I'm trying to do the JUnit of dogs, in the dogsTest.java I have to create dogs and compare them but it's like it doesn't get the information of dogs.java, do you know what I mean?

The package name where my JUnit tests are is model, as well as the main classes (they're in different folders).

Comment: Do you really have the files at the "/" level, or are they in a /user/yourUserName/... directory somewhere?

Comment: Everything is in the folder of the project, which is on the desktop. The structure is the one I said before:

/build/model -- compiled .class files
/src/model -- main .java files
/test/model -- JUnit .java files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the package name is "model", then you should have the folder that contains the package folder in you classpath, not the actual package folder itself.

Try this classpath:

```
CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/junit4.jar;/build;/src;/test
```

But that will only work if your code is actually in /build, /src, and /test.

Let's assume that you have your main project folder is at:

```
/somePath/dogs
```

and your code is in:

```
/somePath/dogs/src/model/Dog.java
/somePath/dogs/test/model/DogTest.java
```

and your jar files are in:

```
/somePath/dogs/build
```

then your classpath should look like:

```
CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/junit4.jar;/somePath/dogs/build;/somePath/dogs/src;/somePath/dogs/test
```

Comment: I always open the terminal in my folder's project so I guess your CLASSPATH should have worked but it didn't. I've tried with the whole path but the error is the same. The weird thing it's that in Netbeans works fine but when I try to do it manually it doesn't work...

Comment: try ';' in your classpath instead of ':'

Comment: I was doing: export classpath... and then compiling with javac instead of doing: java -cp classpath...
Now it works although it doesn't recognized the imports:"package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Test;"

Comment: You do need to have a path to the junit jar file when you compile the program, and when you run the program as well.